# CSS transition tranform does not work in Safari

Tags: css

I want to customise HTML summary's marker, and animate it when the details element opens.
The transition animation works on all browsers except Safari both on desktop and mobile.

```css
details {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #FDF4E3;;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;
  outline: 0;
}

summary {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 2.2rem;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

summary:before {
  content: '';
  border-width: .4rem;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.3rem;
  left: 1rem;
  transform: rotate(0);
  transform-origin: .2rem 50%;
  transition: 1s transform ease;
}

details[open] summary {
   background: #F9D478;
}

details[open]>summary:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}

details p {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Summary</summary>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque porro odit nulla quis voluptas quod similique sunt, nostrum, ea maxime repellendus quisquam harum tempore illum sed, dolore qui aperiam impedit!
  </p>
</details>
```

I have used the following transition that did not work.

1. `-webkit-transition: 1s transform ease;`
2. `-webkit-transition: 1s all ease;`
3. details[open]>summary:before {
   transform: rotate(90deg);
   transition: 1s transform ease;
   }

How to fix issue?

---

These answers did not help.

[css transitions not working in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767037/css-transitions-not-working-in-safari)

[CSS transform and transition not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864226/css-transform-and-transition-not-working-in-safari)

[CSS transition is not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236835/css-transition-is-not-working-in-safari)

[Transitions not working on iOS safari - tried all the different suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67407336/transitions-not-working-on-ios-safari-tried-all-the-different-suffix)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem. You should use`::before` and not `:before`, the single colon version is the legacy format.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known bug: [Bug 213349 -  transitions not when  is opened](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213349):

> Expected behaviour:
> As soon as I click the `<summary>` element, the transition from > to ⌄ should start, and vice versa.
>
> Actual behaviour:
> The transition doesn't start when the `<summary>` element is clicked. The exact conditions that are triggering the transition are somewhat unclear to me. It seems to start only after giving another element focus or moving the cursor outside of the parent element.

While the descriptions does not exactly match the behaviour you encounter, it is likely that those are closely related.

You could solve it with JavaScript, but that is annoying as `toggle`, does not bubble:

```js
var details = document.querySelector("details")

details.addEventListener("toggle", function(evt) {
 details.classList.toggle('open', evt.target.open)
})
```

```css
details {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #282828;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 .1rem 1rem -.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
}

summary {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
  background: #333;
  padding-left: 2.2rem;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

summary:before {
  content: '';
  border-width: .4rem;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.3rem;
  left: 1rem;
  transform: rotate(0);
  transform-origin: .2rem 50%;
  transition: 1s transform ease;
}



/*details[open]>summary:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}*/

details.open>summary:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}



details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}

details p {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Summary</summary>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque porro odit nulla quis voluptas quod similique sunt, nostrum, ea maxime repellendus quisquam harum tempore illum sed, dolore qui aperiam impedit!
  </p>
</details>
```

I wouldn't use the JS solution. I actually just would wait until the bug is fixed, as it is just an eye-candy animation for the open/close marker.

Answer (score 1):

**Animations and Transitions is not supported on pseudo elements for Safari browser.** [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before#browser_compatibility)

You could use a real HTML element for icon then animate that element.

Here is an example with using svg element:

```css
details {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #282828;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 1rem -0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
}

summary {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
  background: #333;
  padding-left: 2.2rem;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

svg {
  width: 1.2rem;
  height: 1.2rem;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

details[open]>summary>svg {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}

details p {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M9 5l7 7-7 7" />
    </svg> 
    Summary
  </summary>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque porro odit nulla quis voluptas quod similique sunt, nostrum, ea maxime repellendus quisquam harum tempore illum sed, dolore qui aperiam impedit!
  </p>
</details>
```

Comment: MDN seems to be outdated here for Safari `15.5` (which I use here) the transitions work on pseudo elements.

Comment: Both transition and animation works. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: @mahan Well the transition obviously does not work for you so Miasmus has a point there. Somehow Safari seems to partially support transitions on pseudo-elements, but it still seems to be incomplete.